# How to show share of total number of procedures?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

G&G hi!

I have a table of data which shows numbers for every procedure of year 2013. For every procedure i have a number and at the end the sum/total of all procedures.

I have to get two numbers: share in total number of procedures and %.

Example: for A procedure i have 4182 in whole of 2013, when i divide this with total number of procedures (which is 589733) i get 0.0070913, the problem is in paper sheet that i got that number is rounded or smth else (correct me if i am wrong) to 0.07.

So how could i get that number? Which function do i have to use?

Please help me on this, total excel noob

Comment: @Cfinley Or Bing ;)

Comment: @ṧнʊß "Bing it" just doesn't have the right ring to it. Still better than "Yahoo it" ;)

Comment: @Cfinley "AltaVista it!", "Ask Jeeves It!".. yup, no good ring to those either. ;)

Comment: If i found the answer i wouldn't be asking you for advice

Comment: Why all the downvotes without any constructive comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a Pivot Table (Insert ribbon) for this, based on your table. On the Pivot Table Field List pane, I would add the Procedure column to the Row Labels zone and the Number of Procedures to the Values zone.  Then I would right-click the Number of Procedures column in the Pivot Table (on the worksheet) and choose Show Values As ... % of Column Total.